# Strapi - error GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}"

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am getting this error in `Strapi` app while building

```
error GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
```

Full Log

```
[2021-11-27T04:22:19.124Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-11-27T04:22:19.127Z] error GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
    at syntaxError (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:15:10)
    at Parser.expectToken (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1413:40)
    at Parser.parseName (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:98:22)
    at Parser.parseFieldDefinition (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:879:21)
    at Parser.optionalMany (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1503:28)
    at Parser.parseFieldsDefinition (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:868:17)
    at Parser.parseObjectTypeDefinition (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:812:23)
    at Parser.parseTypeSystemDefinition (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:708:23)
    at Parser.parseDefinition (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:150:23)
    at Parser.many (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1523:26)
    at Parser.parseDocument (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:115:25)
    at Object.parse (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:31:17)
    at Object.addPolymorphicUnionType (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\strapi-plugin-graphql\services\type-builder.js:188:8) 
    at Object.generateSchema (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\strapi-plugin-graphql\services\schema-generator.js:43:35)      
    at Object.initialize (D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\strapi-plugin-graphql\hooks\graphql\index.js:76:74)
    at D:\Projects\Personal\Aravin.net\website\backend\node_modules\strapi\lib\hooks\index.js:37:28
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c yarn run develop:backend" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

But there is no issue in the graphQL syntax.

Source: https://github.com/Aravin/aravin.net/tree/main/backend

I am trying to fix this issue for a long time, I could see a similar problems all over the internet but there is no proper solution.

Kindly help me.

**Logged the graphql error body and position**

```
 
      scalar Relation
      enum CommentReportReason {
          BAD_LANGAUGE
          DISCRIMINATION
          OTHER
      }
      enum CommentApprovalStatus {
          PENDING
          APPROVED
          REJECTED
      }
      type CommentReport {
          id: ID!
          content: String
          reason: CommentReportReason!
          resolved: Boolean!
          related: Comment
      }

      type Comment {
         
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  blocked: Boolean
  blockedThread: Boolean
  blockReason: String
  points: Int
  authorUser: UsersPermissionsUser
  authorType: String
  authorId: String
  authorName: String
  authorAvatar: String
  removed: Boolean
  relatedSlug: String
  reports: [CommentReport]
  approvalStatus: CommentApprovalStatus

      }

      type CommentsInHierarchy {
        
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  blocked: Boolean
  blockedThread: Boolean
  blockReason: String
  points: Int
  authorUser: UsersPermissionsUser
  authorType: String
  authorId: String
  authorName: String
  authorAvatar: String
  removed: Boolean
  relatedSlug: String
  reports: [CommentReport]
  approvalStatus: CommentApprovalStatus

        children: [Comment]
      }

      type CommentsPagination {
        items: [Comment]!
        total: Int!
        page: Float
      }

      type CommentsWithThread {
        
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  blocked: Boolean
  blockedThread: Boolean
  blockReason: String
  points: Int
  authorUser: UsersPermissionsUser
  authorType: String
  authorId: String
  authorName: String
  authorAvatar: String
  removed: Boolean
  relatedSlug: String
  reports: [CommentReport]
  approvalStatus: CommentApprovalStatus

        threadOf: Comment
      }

      type CommentsFindOne {
        selected: CommentsWithThread
        level: [Comment]!
      }

      type CommentsContentTypes {
      key: String!
      value: String!
      }

      type CommentsRelatedContentType {
        contentManager: Boolean
        isSingle: Boolean
        url: String
      }

      type CommentsRelatedContentTypes {
        
      }

      type CommentsConfig {
        contentsTypes: [CommentsContentTypes]!
        relatedContentTypes: CommentsRelatedContentTypes
      }

      type CommentsContentType {
        key: String!
        value: String
      }
      
      type CommentRemove {
        id: ID!
      }

      input NewCommentRelated {
        refId: String!
        ref: String!
        field: String!
      }

      input CommentNew {
        authorId: String
        authorName: String
        authorEmail: String
        content: String!
        authorUsername: String
        threadOf: String
        related: [NewCommentRelated!]!
        approvalStatus: CommentApprovalStatus
      }
        
    input FileInfoInput {
      name: String
      alternativeText: String
      caption: String
    }
   
    type UsersPermissionsMe {
      id: ID!
      username: String!
      email: String!
      confirmed: Boolean
      blocked: Boolean
      role: UsersPermissionsMeRole
    }

    type UsersPermissionsMeRole {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      description: String
      type: String
    }

    input UsersPermissionsRegisterInput {
      username: String!
      email: String!
      password: String!
    }

    input UsersPermissionsLoginInput {
      identifier: String!
      password: String!
      provider: String = "local"
    }

    type UsersPermissionsLoginPayload {
      jwt: String
      user: UsersPermissionsMe!
    }

    type UserPermissionsPasswordPayload {
      ok: Boolean!
    }
        
type Article {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
title: String!
description: String!
content: String!
slug: String!
category: Category
image: UploadFile
author: Writer
published_at: DateTime
tags(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Tags]}

type ArticleConnection {values: [Article]
groupBy: ArticleGroupBy
aggregate: ArticleAggregator}

type ArticleAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type ArticleGroupBy {id: [ArticleConnectionId]
created_at: [ArticleConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [ArticleConnectionUpdated_at]
title: [ArticleConnectionTitle]
description: [ArticleConnectionDescription]
content: [ArticleConnectionContent]
slug: [ArticleConnectionSlug]
category: [ArticleConnectionCategory]
image: [ArticleConnectionImage]
author: [ArticleConnectionAuthor]
published_at: [ArticleConnectionPublished_at]}

type ArticleConnectionId {key: ID
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionTitle {key: String
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionDescription {key: String
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionContent {key: String
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionSlug {key: String
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionCategory {key: ID
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionImage {key: ID
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionAuthor {key: ID
connection: ArticleConnection}

type ArticleConnectionPublished_at {key: DateTime
connection: ArticleConnection}
      input ArticleInput {

        title: String!
description: String!
content: String!
slug: String!
category: ID
image: ID
author: ID
tags: [ID]
published_at: DateTime
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editArticleInput {
        
        title: String
description: String
content: String
slug: String
category: ID
image: ID
author: ID
tags: [ID]
published_at: DateTime
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createArticleInput { data: ArticleInput }
          type createArticlePayload { article: Article }
        

          input updateArticleInput  { where: InputID, data: editArticleInput }
          type updateArticlePayload { article: Article }
        

          input deleteArticleInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteArticlePayload { article: Article }
        
type Category {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
name: String!
slug: String!
articles(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Article]}

type CategoryConnection {values: [Category]
groupBy: CategoryGroupBy
aggregate: CategoryAggregator}

type CategoryAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type CategoryGroupBy {id: [CategoryConnectionId]
created_at: [CategoryConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [CategoryConnectionUpdated_at]
name: [CategoryConnectionName]
slug: [CategoryConnectionSlug]}

type CategoryConnectionId {key: ID
connection: CategoryConnection}

type CategoryConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: CategoryConnection}

type CategoryConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: CategoryConnection}

type CategoryConnectionName {key: String
connection: CategoryConnection}

type CategoryConnectionSlug {key: String
connection: CategoryConnection}
      input CategoryInput {

        name: String!
slug: String!
articles: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editCategoryInput {
        
        name: String
slug: String
articles: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createCategoryInput { data: CategoryInput }
          type createCategoryPayload { category: Category }
        

          input updateCategoryInput  { where: InputID, data: editCategoryInput }
          type updateCategoryPayload { category: Category }
        

          input deleteCategoryInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteCategoryPayload { category: Category }
        
type Global {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
favicon: UploadFile
siteName: String!
defaultSeo: ComponentSharedSeo}

      input GlobalInput {

        favicon: ID
siteName: String!
defaultSeo: ComponentSharedSeoInput!
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editGlobalInput {
        
        favicon: ID
siteName: String
defaultSeo: editComponentSharedSeoInput
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input updateGlobalInput  { data: editGlobalInput }
          type updateGlobalPayload { global: Global }
        

          type deleteGlobalPayload { global: Global }
        
type Homepage {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
seo: ComponentSharedSeo
hero: ComponentSectionsHero}

      input HomepageInput {

        seo: ComponentSharedSeoInput
hero: ComponentSectionsHeroInput!
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editHomepageInput {
        
        seo: editComponentSharedSeoInput
hero: editComponentSectionsHeroInput
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input updateHomepageInput  { data: editHomepageInput }
          type updateHomepagePayload { homepage: Homepage }
        

          type deleteHomepagePayload { homepage: Homepage }
        
type Tags {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
slug: String
color: String
Name: String
published_at: DateTime
articles(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Article]}

type TagsConnection {values: [Tags]
groupBy: TagsGroupBy
aggregate: TagsAggregator}

type TagsAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type TagsGroupBy {id: [TagsConnectionId]
created_at: [TagsConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [TagsConnectionUpdated_at]
slug: [TagsConnectionSlug]
color: [TagsConnectionColor]
Name: [TagsConnectionName]
published_at: [TagsConnectionPublished_at]}

type TagsConnectionId {key: ID
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionSlug {key: String
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionColor {key: String
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionName {key: String
connection: TagsConnection}

type TagsConnectionPublished_at {key: DateTime
connection: TagsConnection}
      input TagInput {

        slug: String
color: String
Name: String
articles: [ID]
published_at: DateTime
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editTagInput {
        
        slug: String
color: String
Name: String
articles: [ID]
published_at: DateTime
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createTagInput { data: TagInput }
          type createTagPayload { tag: Tags }
        

          input updateTagInput  { where: InputID, data: editTagInput }
          type updateTagPayload { tag: Tags }
        

          input deleteTagInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteTagPayload { tag: Tags }
        
type Writer {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
name: String
picture: UploadFile
email: String
articles(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Article]}

type WriterConnection {values: [Writer]
groupBy: WriterGroupBy
aggregate: WriterAggregator}

type WriterAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type WriterGroupBy {id: [WriterConnectionId]
created_at: [WriterConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [WriterConnectionUpdated_at]
name: [WriterConnectionName]
picture: [WriterConnectionPicture]
email: [WriterConnectionEmail]}

type WriterConnectionId {key: ID
connection: WriterConnection}

type WriterConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: WriterConnection}

type WriterConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: WriterConnection}

type WriterConnectionName {key: String
connection: WriterConnection}

type WriterConnectionPicture {key: ID
connection: WriterConnection}

type WriterConnectionEmail {key: String
connection: WriterConnection}
      input WriterInput {

        name: String
picture: ID
articles: [ID]
email: String
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editWriterInput {
        
        name: String
picture: ID
articles: [ID]
email: String
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createWriterInput { data: WriterInput }
          type createWriterPayload { writer: Writer }
        

          input updateWriterInput  { where: InputID, data: editWriterInput }
          type updateWriterPayload { writer: Writer }
        

          input deleteWriterInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteWriterPayload { writer: Writer }
        
type CommentsComment {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
content: String!
blocked: Boolean
blockedThread: Boolean
blockReason: String
points: Int
authorUser: UsersPermissionsUser
authorType: String
authorId: String
authorName: String
authorEmail: String
authorAvatar: String
removed: Boolean
threadOf: CommentsComment
approvalStatus: String
related(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Morph]
reports(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [CommentsReport]}

      input CommentInput {

        content: String!
blocked: Boolean
blockedThread: Boolean
blockReason: String
points: Int
authorUser: ID
authorType: String
authorId: String
authorName: String
authorEmail: String
authorAvatar: String
removed: Boolean
relatedSlug: String
related: [ID]
reports: [ID]
threadOf: ID
approvalStatus: String
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editCommentInput {
        
        content: String
blocked: Boolean
blockedThread: Boolean
blockReason: String
points: Int
authorUser: ID
authorType: String
authorId: String
authorName: String
authorEmail: String
authorAvatar: String
removed: Boolean
relatedSlug: String
related: [ID]
reports: [ID]
threadOf: ID
approvalStatus: String
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    
enum ENUM_COMMENTSREPORT_REASON {
    BAD_LANGUAGE
    DISCRIMINATION
    OTHER
}
type CommentsReport {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
content: String
reason: ENUM_COMMENTSREPORT_REASON!
resolved: Boolean
related: CommentsComment}

      input ReportInput {

        content: String
reason: ENUM_COMMENTSREPORT_REASON
resolved: Boolean
related: ID
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editReportInput {
        
        content: String
reason: ENUM_COMMENTSREPORT_REASON
resolved: Boolean
related: ID
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    
type UploadFile {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
name: String!
alternativeText: String
caption: String
width: Int
height: Int
formats: JSON
hash: String!
ext: String
mime: String!
size: Float!
url: String!
previewUrl: String
provider: String!
provider_metadata: JSON
related(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Morph]}

type UploadFileConnection {values: [UploadFile]
groupBy: UploadFileGroupBy
aggregate: UploadFileAggregator}

type UploadFileAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int
sum: UploadFileAggregatorSum
avg: UploadFileAggregatorAvg
min: UploadFileAggregatorMin
max: UploadFileAggregatorMax}

type UploadFileAggregatorSum {width: Float
height: Float
size: Float}

type UploadFileAggregatorAvg {width: Float
height: Float
size: Float}

type UploadFileAggregatorMin {width: Float
height: Float
size: Float}

type UploadFileAggregatorMax {width: Float
height: Float
size: Float}

type UploadFileGroupBy {id: [UploadFileConnectionId]
created_at: [UploadFileConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [UploadFileConnectionUpdated_at]
name: [UploadFileConnectionName]
alternativeText: [UploadFileConnectionAlternativeText]
caption: [UploadFileConnectionCaption]
width: [UploadFileConnectionWidth]
height: [UploadFileConnectionHeight]
formats: [UploadFileConnectionFormats]
hash: [UploadFileConnectionHash]
ext: [UploadFileConnectionExt]
mime: [UploadFileConnectionMime]
size: [UploadFileConnectionSize]
url: [UploadFileConnectionUrl]
previewUrl: [UploadFileConnectionPreviewUrl]
provider: [UploadFileConnectionProvider]
provider_metadata: [UploadFileConnectionProvider_metadata]}

type UploadFileConnectionId {key: ID
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionName {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionAlternativeText {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionCaption {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionWidth {key: Int
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionHeight {key: Int
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionFormats {key: JSON
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionHash {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionExt {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionMime {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionSize {key: Float
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionUrl {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionPreviewUrl {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionProvider {key: String
connection: UploadFileConnection}

type UploadFileConnectionProvider_metadata {key: JSON
connection: UploadFileConnection}
      input FileInput {

        name: String!
alternativeText: String
caption: String
width: Int
height: Int
formats: JSON
hash: String!
ext: String
mime: String!
size: Float!
url: String!
previewUrl: String
provider: String!
provider_metadata: JSON
related: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editFileInput {
        
        name: String
alternativeText: String
caption: String
width: Int
height: Int
formats: JSON
hash: String
ext: String
mime: String
size: Float
url: String
previewUrl: String
provider: String
provider_metadata: JSON
related: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input deleteFileInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteFilePayload { file: UploadFile }
        
type UsersPermissionsPermission {id: ID!
type: String!
controller: String!
action: String!
enabled: Boolean!
policy: String
role: UsersPermissionsRole}

type UsersPermissionsRole {id: ID!
name: String!
description: String
type: String
permissions(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UsersPermissionsPermission]
users(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UsersPermissionsUser]}

type UsersPermissionsRoleConnection {values: [UsersPermissionsRole]
groupBy: UsersPermissionsRoleGroupBy
aggregate: UsersPermissionsRoleAggregator}

type UsersPermissionsRoleAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type UsersPermissionsRoleGroupBy {id: [UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionId]
name: [UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionName]
description: [UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionDescription]
type: [UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionType]}

type UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionId {key: ID
connection: UsersPermissionsRoleConnection}

type UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionName {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsRoleConnection}

type UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionDescription {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsRoleConnection}

type UsersPermissionsRoleConnectionType {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsRoleConnection}
      input RoleInput {

        name: String!
description: String
type: String
permissions: [ID]
users: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editRoleInput {
        
        name: String
description: String
type: String
permissions: [ID]
users: [ID]
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createRoleInput { data: RoleInput }
          type createRolePayload { role: UsersPermissionsRole }
        

          input updateRoleInput  { where: InputID, data: editRoleInput }
          type updateRolePayload { role: UsersPermissionsRole }
        

          input deleteRoleInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteRolePayload { role: UsersPermissionsRole }
        
type UsersPermissionsUser {id: ID!
created_at: DateTime!
updated_at: DateTime!
username: String!
email: String!
provider: String
confirmed: Boolean
blocked: Boolean
role: UsersPermissionsRole}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnection {values: [UsersPermissionsUser]
groupBy: UsersPermissionsUserGroupBy
aggregate: UsersPermissionsUserAggregator}

type UsersPermissionsUserAggregator {count: Int
totalCount: Int}

type UsersPermissionsUserGroupBy {id: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionId]
created_at: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionCreated_at]
updated_at: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionUpdated_at]
username: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionUsername]
email: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionEmail]
provider: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionProvider]
confirmed: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionConfirmed]
blocked: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionBlocked]
role: [UsersPermissionsUserConnectionRole]}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionId {key: ID
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionCreated_at {key: DateTime
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionUpdated_at {key: DateTime
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionUsername {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionEmail {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionProvider {key: String
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionConfirmed {key: Boolean
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionBlocked {key: Boolean
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}

type UsersPermissionsUserConnectionRole {key: ID
connection: UsersPermissionsUserConnection}
      input UserInput {

        username: String!
email: String!
provider: String
password: String
resetPasswordToken: String
confirmationToken: String
confirmed: Boolean
blocked: Boolean
role: ID
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }

      input editUserInput {
        
        username: String
email: String
provider: String
password: String
resetPasswordToken: String
confirmationToken: String
confirmed: Boolean
blocked: Boolean
role: ID
created_by: ID
updated_by: ID
      }
    

          input createUserInput { data: UserInput }
          type createUserPayload { user: UsersPermissionsUser }
        

          input updateUserInput  { where: InputID, data: editUserInput }
          type updateUserPayload { user: UsersPermissionsUser }
        

          input deleteUserInput  { where: InputID }
          type deleteUserPayload { user: UsersPermissionsUser }
        
type ComponentSectionsHero {id: ID!
title: String!}

      input ComponentSectionsHeroInput {

        title: String!
      }

      input editComponentSectionsHeroInput {
        id: ID
        title: String
      }
    
type ComponentSharedSeo {id: ID!
metaTitle: String!
metaDescription: String!
shareImage: UploadFile}

      input ComponentSharedSeoInput {

        metaTitle: String!
metaDescription: String!
shareImage: ID
      }

      input editComponentSharedSeoInput {
        id: ID
        metaTitle: String
metaDescription: String
shareImage: ID
      }
```

Position: 2083

Comment: Why is it so weirdly indented?

Comment: It was auto-generated @drum

Comment: I also stuck on this error by adding new plugin https://github.com/VirtusLab-Open-Source/strapi-plugin-comments

Comment: I also had a similar problem. I faced why adding strapi comment plugin.